# Can't get Visual Studio Code C includes to work properly

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have been playing with Microsoft visual studio code in Ubuntu for a couple of days but I have found a problem that really annoys me;
when I use custom includes the clang error parser gives me this error:

```
physical_memory.c
/arch/x86/physical_memory.h' file not found (10,10)
```

But the fact is that I have already added the include folder to the c_cpp_properties.json as follows:

```
    {
        "name": "Linux",
        "includePath": ["/usr/include",
                        "/home/manuel/Documentos/OSDEV/XeonOS/kernel/include",
                        "/opt/cross/lib/gcc/i686-elf/5.4.0/include"],
        "browse" : {
            "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders" : true,
            "databaseFilename" : ""
        }
    },
```

I have checked many times that the file names are correct and tried with include/ and include/* but it didn't work, also, the project compiles and works as usual.

By the way this is the code line that causes the error:

```
#include <arch/x86/physical_memory.h>
```

I wouldn't mind having this error but for some reason when an include error is found the clang real time error parser stops working on that file, and that is something that I find very annoying.

Do you know how can I fix it?

Comment: `#include "arch/x86/physical_memory.h"`

Comment: @RawN Already tried that

Comment: 1) Verify that the header file exists in the specified directory.  2) In your version of Visual Studio, find the properties for setting include paths and add the path to the list.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I have verified that many times and 2, I'm using the visual studio code, not visual studio so i execute my own makefiles where the include paths are the same than above

Comment: Nobody knows how to fix it :?

Comment: If you re talking about intellicense support - you have to add same include paths to the "browse" / "path" subnode - At least on my system it duplicates the "includePath" node